# Ошибка при решении задачи из leetcode

Tags: c

Это задача из leetcode.

С клавиатуры вводиться target и набор чисел. Если число `target` есть в наборе, то нужно вернуть индекс этого числа. Если нет, то нужно вернуть потенциальный индекс, как если бы числа стояли по порядку.

Пример1:

```
Input:
nums = [1,2,5,6,7], target=2; 

Output: 1
```

Пример2:

```
nums=[1,2,5,6,7], target=3;
Output: 2
```

Первый кейс всегда срабатывает корректно, но второй всегда возвращает 0.

Как исправить данную ситуацию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь код текстом, а не картинкой. Добавь ссылку на саму задачу

Comment: `break` не нужен. И возможен ли по условию задачи такой пример: `nums=[1, 9], target=5;`?

Comment: Может во 2-м цикле `for` за условие взять `target > nums[i]`, т.е. ближайшее. И тогда вернуть `i + 1`.

Comment: int searchInsert(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        if(target==nums[i]){
            return i;
        }
        
    } for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
      if((target)-(nums[i])==1){
          return i++;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Пробовал target>nums[i], все равно выводит 0(

Comment: Вариант [1,9], target=5 возможен

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял условие, то

```
int searchInsert(int * nums, int size, int tgt)
{
    int idx = 0;
    while(idx < size && nums[idx] < tgt) ++idx;
    return idx;
}
```

Или я неправ? Тогда приведите контрпример, чтоб я правильно понял условие.